# Akka-HTTP crashes when using RMQ driver

Tags: scala, gradle, akka-http

I'm trying to run akka-http with rabbit mq client ('amqp-scala-client_2.12')

using scala version 2.12.

but i get an exception that:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function1$class
at akka.http.scaladsl.server.PathMatcher.<init>(PathMatcher.scala:20)
at akka.http.scaladsl.server.ImplicitPathMatcherConstruction$$anon$8.<init>(PathMatcher.scala:267)
at akka.http.scaladsl.server.ImplicitPathMatcherConstruction$class._regex2PathMatcher(PathMatcher.scala:267)
at akka.http.scaladsl.server.PathMatcher$._regex2PathMatcher(PathMatcher.scala:105)
at         
  akka.http.scaladsl.server.PathMatchers$class.$init$(PathMatcher.scala:461)
at akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives$.<init>(Directives.scala:40)
at akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives$.<clinit>(Directives.scala)
at WebServer$.main(WebServer.scala:41)
at WebServer.main(WebServer.scala)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function1$class
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I guess it is because version collision because when disabling the rmq its works.

can you  help or suggest other rmq library that will work thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `akka-http` (`akka-http-core_2.11`) which is compiled with Scala 2.11, but your RMQ driver is 2.12. You need to decide which version of Scala you're using, and then use the driver compiled *with that version*. If you decide to use Scala 2.12, you need [`akka-http-core_2.12`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-http-core_2.12).